# Is there a way to run Spartacus on SAP Hybris 6.2?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

Is there a way i can run Spartacus on Hybris 6.2?

I am running 6.2 on my localhost computer.

SAP website says it have to be version 18 and above.

Thanks,

Comment: [**Spartacus**?](https://youtu.be/FKCmyiljKo0?t=65) Typical. Spend all day looking for one, and a thousand turn up.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't.

From: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus

```
SAP Commerce Cloud instance

- Release 1905 recommended
- Works with 1811 and 1808, with reduced functionality
```

Additionally, 6.6 and below are already End-of-Life. i.e. SAP is no longer supporting them. The minimum is now 6.7, but even this is not recommended for Spartacus.